# If we let $A$ be an $m × n$ matrix. Suppose that the rows of $A$ are linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

If we let $A$ be an $m × n$ matrix. Suppose that the rows of $A$ are linearly independent.
(a) Is $A^TA$ invertible? Explain.
(b) Is $AA^T$
invertible? Explain.

So if the rows of $A$ are linearly independent then $Ax=0$. But how do I go about proving a and b?

Comment: I think you meant $A^T x = 0 \Rightarrow x= 0$.

Comment: yes sorry thats what i meant

Comment: This has been so many times on this site. Please search before asking a question.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are working over the reals.

Assume the rows of $A$ are linearly independent. That means that the only solution to $xA = 0$ is $x = 0$ where $x$ is a row vector of length $m$.

Now assume that $AA^T$ is not invertible. Then there exists a row vector $v$ such that $vAA^T = 0$ (easy to see if we are over the reals or any other field, a little harder over arbitrary rings). But then also $vAA^Tv^T = 0$. 
Setting $x := vA$ we thus have $xx^T = 0$, which might ring some bells and then lead to a contradiction.

Comment: @ Bemte what contradiction is this?

Comment: There's technically no need to appeal to contradiction here. Just let $v$ be such that $vAA^T=0$, deduce that $vA=0$. Then conclude that $v=0$ by linear independence of rows in $A$. I like a proof by contradiction as much as the next guy, but some times starting a proof with an assumption and concluding with a contradiction is just unnecessary filler, and the proof itself works just as well and looks better without it.